# How wait between events in Node Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

I try to use NodeJs to put a time interval between every event 'change'

I tried using a `setTimeout()` but this didn't work because wait the time and process ALL the files at the same time.

```
fs.watch('Desktop/folder', function(event, filename){
  if (event == 'Change'){
    // sleep(10);
    console.log('processing...')
    process(filename);
)}})
```

What I doing wrong?

Result expected:

(put 5 files in 'Desktop/folder')

```
> processing...
(wait 10 seconds)
> processing...
(wait 10 seconds)
> processing...
(wait 10 seconds)
> processing...
(wait 10 seconds)
> processing...
(wait 10 seconds)
```

Actual result:

(put 5 files in 'Desktop/folder')

```
(wait 10 seconds)
> processing...
> processing...
> processing...
> processing...
> processing...
```

Comment: *"What I doing wrong?"* You assumed that `setTimeout` somehow blocks the current JavaScript execution, but it doesn't. It merely schedules some code to be executed in the future, and the remaining statement of the current execution context are still evaluated. If you want the behavior you described you'd have to build your own queue. The event handler adds items to the queue and some other function picks them up every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are correct to use setTimeout(). This would execute to the process method 10 ms after the 'Change' event happens. However, you probably need to include the console.log statement in the setTimeout() method in order to see the output you desire.

```
fs.watch('Desktop/folder', function(event, filename){
  if (event == 'Change'){
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('processing...')
        process(filename);
    }, 10000)
)}})
```

Comment: to *interval* what exactly?

Comment: But if I put 50 files the script is going to wait for 10 seconds and process all the files at the same time. This is what i don't want.

Comment: If you wait 10ms, it may appear that they are processing right away. If you wait 10000 ms, it will wait 10 seconds between each call to the process function. I edited the code snip above to reflect 10000ms wait time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setInterval` to put Intervals in processing. You can read more about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args)

```
fs.watch('Desktop/folder', function(event, filename){
if (event == 'Change'){
setInterval(() => {
    console.log('processing...')
    process(filename);
}, 10000)
)}})
```